# Stale objects when using polymorphic many to many relationships in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, class, oop, laravel-5, polymorphic-associations

I wrote a class called `Categorizable` that allows for a polymorphic many to many relationship between a class that extends it and the class `Category`. It works great but I noticed that if I call a method to add a Category to a categorizable object it adds the entry on the join table but my actual object isn't updated. If I try to call `categories` on my object, it's not updated with what's on the database. I would like to keep my objects up to date so i don't have to query the database for it each time I add a category.

**Categorizable.php**

```
class Categorizable extends Model{

public function categories(){
    return $this->morphToMany(Category::class, 'categorizable');
}

public function addCategory(\App\Category $category){
    if ( $this->isValidCategory($category) ){
        if ( $this->hasCategory($category) ){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            $this->categories()->save($category);
            return true;
        }
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

public function removeCategory(\App\Category $category){
    if ( $this->isValidCategory($category) ) {
        if ($this->hasCategory($category)) {
            $this->categories()->detach($category);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

public function hasCategory(\App\Category $category){
    return $this->categories->contains($category);
}

public function isValidCategory(\App\Category $category){
    if ( $category->category_type === get_class( $this ) ){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

If this is not possible with Laravel 5.2 or considered bad practice, please say so. If you have any recommendations on how I could improve this, that is also welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider handling this in a controller as explained in https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

It will simplify what you want to achieve. Let's assume the categories are related to an article and the controller is ArticleController. $article is the model object and the isValidCategory() check is done. Add a category or remove one becomes:

```
$article->categories()->attach($category->id);
$article->categories()->detach($category->id);
```

Resetting all relationships of that article:

```
$article->categories()->detach();
$article->categories()->attach($categories); //flat array
```

Or do this in one line:

```
$article->categories()->sync($categories);
```

Remember, you can either use **one** id or an **array** of id's like [1, 2, 3]

*Note:* `$category->id` is an assumption, if $category is the id, then obviously, use `$category`

Comment: Following up on this question. You are right, `sync` was much more useful to use in the controller than trying to abstract the functionality into a new class. `syncWithoutDetaching` is also very useful if you need to add new relationships without losing existin ones, as sync will drop existing rows on the join table before inserting new ones.